# Making Law a synonym of Legality

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

**Update: I merged the Law tag into Legality.**

[legality](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legality) has 32 questions, [law](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) 2.

The [tag wiki](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/834) for [legality](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legality) is

> The legalities associated with aspects of the outdoors. Ask questions using this tag if you wish to know if an activity is legal or what legal constraints are associated with a particular outdoor activity.
>
> Please note legalities are often country specific so you should include what country(ies) you wish to obtain information on.

The [tag wiki](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/834) for [law](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) is

> Questions referencing the legality, laws, by-laws, of an outdoor pursuit.
>
> Questions referencing the legality, laws, by-laws, of an outdoor pursuit. This may be used in connection with a country tag.

Can we make [law](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) a synonym of [legality](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legality)?

Comment: I'm thinking law might be best as the master, with legality a synonym

Comment: I think I agree with Rory, Law seems the more common word

Comment: Merge them!  As for which to choose, is law a more recent tag than legality?  Is that why legality is used more often?  Note that law has the term "bylaws", which is very different from "law".  Bylaws are just rules.  Is there a tag for rules?

Comment: @ab2 did you read the bold part at the top of the question :)

Comment: I'm skimming things too fast.  Merging law into legality is fine with me.